# Trigger Cannot query on same table?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

I want to create a trigger an BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE TRIGGER on a table Customer:

```
Create table customer
(CustNum Number,
DebitNum Number
);
```

The validation I  need to do in trigger is that a customer is not assigned with same DebitNum twice.

So my trigger code is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER XX_MYTRIG
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE
ON CUSTOMER
DECLARE
ln_count Number;
BEGIN
    Select count(CustNum) into ln_count
    from customer
    where CustNum:=:New.CustNum 
    and DebitNum:=NEW.DebitNum;
    IF ln_count>0 then
        RAISE fnd_api.g_exc_error;
    END IF;
END;
```

When I insert or update I noticed that the select statement was not even executed. 
How I can query on same table...?

Comment: Your data model is puzzling.  We would expect CUSTNUM to be the primary key of a table called CUSTOMER.  So how can the any customer be given more than one DEBITNUM, duplicate or otherwise?

Comment: Do you mean that one customer can't be assigned the same DebitNum twice; or that two customers can't be assigned the same DebitNum? How do you know the select isn't executed - other than that you're missing a colon before the second NEW in the code you posted, so the trigger is probably invalid?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by adding a unique constraint on columns CustNum and DebitNum. This approach will be much more effective than implemented with trigger.

```
ALTER TABLE customer
ADD CONSTRAINT constraint_name UNIQUE (CustNum , DebitNum);
```